# Preventing users from changing form values of a form using "inspect" in his web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am building an application based on node.js and using handlebars as view engine.  the problem is I have a form that when submitted it inserts data into the database.  this forms passes some values that the user does not see, like the bookingAmount for example.  I currently use a hidden input field that contains the value for the booking which is passed to nodeJs through req.body.  the problem is the user can open the "inspect element" in his browser and change this booking Amount before submiting the form !! how can I prevent such thing from happening ?
**code for the handlebars form (inside page bookingDetails.handlebars)**:

```
<form action="/finish" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
    <input type="hidden" name="bookingId" value="{{data.bookingId}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="{{data.user.userId}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="bookingAmount" value="{{data.bookingAmount}}">
    <button type="submit"  id="finish">Finish Tour</button>
</form>
```

the above data.XXXXX is passed on from nodeJs when the page loads by the below code:

```
var bookingDetails=bookings.findOne({where:{bookingId: req.body.bookingId}, include: [{model: locations},{model: user}).then((bookingDetails)=>{
            res.render('tPages/bookingDetails',{data: bookingDetails})
        })
```

The same problem exists for some buttons on the page.  the page contains buttons like edit , cancel and submit.  I want to make those buttons enabled or disabled depending on the booking status.  I am using a script in the handlebars page to change the disabled property to true or false depending on the booking status.  still the user can change the "disabled" property in his browser and use the button, here is the script I use:

```
<script>
    status='{{data.bookingStatus}}'
    if (status=='accepted'){
        document.getElementById("cancel").disabled = true;
    }else if (status=='pending'){
        document.getElementById("finish").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("noshow").disabled = true;
    }else if (status=='finished' || status =='noshow' || status=='cancelled' || status=='rejected'){
        document.getElementById("cancel").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("finish").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("noshow").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

what is the solution for such issues ?

Comment: There are workarounds that can work to an extent, but the issue is fundamentally impossible - you cannot trust anything done or verified on the client, because the client can run whatever code the client wants, if they're determined enough.

Comment: Why do you post `userId` and `bookingAmount` along with `bookingId`? Isn't the booking on the server already decorated with a userId and bookingAmount?

If you _have_ to send userId and bookingAmount, you could:

1) calculate a hash on the server from the values you don't want the user to tamper with
2) include the hash as a hidden field
3) when server recieve the fields (and hash), recalculate the hash on the server again
4) compare the original hash to the new hash and fail if mismatch

This ressembles ASP.NET WebForms very much.

Answer (score 2):

### Do Not Rely on user input

Even if you try hacks to disable the right click menu etc. these are easily cirumvented (I can just post the form information directly using cURL or similar).

Validate on the server ALWAYS.

If some items need to be disabled, make sure the same logic applies on the server and reject information that does not follow your business rules.

Also don't disable the context menu or try and prevent the browser doing things it is designed to do, this will only lead to other issues, frustrates users and provides you with little / no protection at all.

Comment: what about enable and disable button in the script?

Comment: Pass that information as you would normally, send the `status` back from the server and apply logic on the front end (as you have described). The problem you face is things like relying on the front-end to validate information (e.g. booking amount). Anything that goes to the browser can be changed by the end user, so you need to make sure that any important information like that is handled on the server and passed to the front end, then validated on the back end. For example if the `status` you send back is 'accepted' make sure the server will not accept a 'cancel' request at all.